# Divergence of $H$ Maxwell equation

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, maxwell-equations, vector-fields, calculus

In the below screenshot from this paper (link below), why is the 2nd Maxwell equation ($\nabla \cdot H = 0$) not automatically satisfied when the 4th Maxwell equation is satisfied? I don't understand this, since I thought div of any curl is 0, so $\nabla \cdot H = 0$ should be satisfied. This logic is applied to explaining why the 1st Maxwell equation is automatically satisfied when the 3rd Maxwell equation is satisfied.

Paper link: https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.85.245103

[image]

Comment: Technically $\omega=0$ is also a solution and does not mean H's divergence is zero

Answer (score 0):

Properly, the four [macroscopic Maxwell equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations#Macroscopic_formulation) are

$$
\nabla \cdot \vec{D} = \rho_{f}
$$
$$
\nabla \cdot \vec{B} = \vec{0}
$$
$$
\nabla \times \vec{E} = -\frac{1}{c}\frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t}
$$
$$
\nabla \times \vec{H} = \vec{J}_{f} + \frac{\partial\vec{D}}{\partial t} 
$$

From this, you can see that it is in fact *the time partial derivative* of the divergence of $\vec{B}$ or $\vec{H}$ that is implied to be $0$ by the your fourth equation (the third here). The $i\omega$ in your book is referring to the time derivative. It is operating under a standard complex exponential framework.

Note that the $\vec{H}$ curl equation (or $\vec{B}$ from a vacuum perspective) would preclude $\vec{D}$ (or $\vec{E}$) from ever having nonzero divergence if not for the time partial (with no current of course). This would mean that the charge density would always be 0.

EDIT: Since this explanation is bothering you a bit, let me put it into less controversial terms. From the standard vacuum Maxwell equations (with no current):

$$
\nabla \times \vec{B} = \frac{\partial \vec{E}}{\partial t}
$$
$$
0 = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\nabla \cdot \vec{E}
$$

From the first one:

$$
0 = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_{0}}
$$
$$
0 = \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}
$$

All this tells us is that in the absence of any currents, the charge density is constant. If the current density $\vec{J}$ had been initially included, we would instead have an equation relating current density and charge density. It would just be a charge conservation equation. Something like

$$
0 = \nabla \cdot \vec{J} + \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}
$$

Obviously I cannot meaningfully do this for you with the other pair (which was your actual question) until someone one day discovers a magnetic "charge" / monopole. However, mathematically there is no difference. Nothing in the Maxwell curl equations preclude charges / monopoles, because obviously the electric ones exist. It is the second equation that fixes the density of the magnetic ones to 0 always. That equation is really just the never before violated observational fact that no one has seen such a magnetic charge. It is not any sort of mathematical necessity.

It is an interesting exercise to write out fully symmetric Maxwell equations (meaning symmetric and electricity and magnetism).

Comment: Thanks for the answer -- I agree with your first point that the $i\omega$ term comes from the time derivative. But if you take the divergence of your third equation, isn't $\nabla \cdot B = 0$ automatically satisfied? I don't see why the paper needs to expand in terms of basis functions where $\nabla \cdot H = 0$ in order to guarantee that $\nabla \cdot H = 0$ .

Comment: While $\vec{B}$ divergence free is one solution, there are  others. It is not the magnetic field that is divergence free from the third, it is it's time partial. That does not require the magnetic field to be divergence free. Exactly, it is $\nabla \cdot \frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t} = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening here is just that all of you are reading it wrong. It is the author's fault for writing it so misleadingly.

You are correct that
$$\vec H\propto\vec\nabla\times\vec E\qquad\implies\qquad\vec\nabla\cdot\vec H=0$$
and that it is the same reasoning being used for the other set.

But the author is simply asserting the *technically correct* statement that $\vec\nabla\cdot\vec H=0$ can be satisfied if you expand $\vec H$ in basis functions that have zero divergence.

The point is that the author is most likely going to argue that we can get the correct solutions to all 4 Maxwell's equations if we expand $\vec H$ in terms of zero divergence basis functions, deriving the relationships those basis functions have to satisfy, instead of working in terms of those 4 equations directly.

Answer (score -1):

It seems to be satisfied, but the author probably wanted to write the four Maxwell equations explicitly instead of writing only the minimum necessary.

"Seems to be" means assuming $i\omega\mu_0$ is constant in this context (which seems to be the case).